# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on get function in GORM

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0.10

I'm getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when i try to retrieve domain class object using get function in GORM.

**DOMAIN CLASS**

```
class Connect {
    int id
    long profileid
    String username
    char type
    char superSub
    String time
    char class_
    boolean isapilogin

    static mapping = {
        table "CONNECT"
        version false
        id column: "ID"
        profileid column: "PROFILEID"
        username column: "USERNAME"
        type column: "TYPE"
        superSub column: "SUPER_SUB"
        time column: "TIME"
        class_ column: "CLASS"
        isapilogin column: "ISAPILOGIN"

    }

    static constraints = {
        username maxSize: 40
        type maxSize: 1
        superSub maxSize: 1
        time maxSize: 14
        class_ maxSize: 1
    }
}
```

**MYSQL DATABASE TABLE**

ID              | int(10) unsigned
PROFILEID       | bigint(20) unsigned
USERNAME        | varchar(40)
TYPE            | char(1)
SUPER_SUB       | char(1)
TIME            | varchar(14)
CLASS           | char(1)
ISAPILOGIN      | tinyint(1)

**MYCONTROLLER**

```
class DemoController {
    def check() {
        int id = 1001;
        Connect data = Connect.get(id)  // exception at this line
        data.save()
        render "check"

    }
}
```

**MYSQL TABLE DATA**

ID      PROFILEID |USERNAME | TYPE | SUPER_SUB | TIME |CLASS|ISAPILOGIN

1001 |  4 | ABHINAV  |   | P      | 1461235989 | A |          0

1002 |  5 | GAVAN | S | P      |1450155084 | A     |  1

the exception is coming when i call get on ID 1001 and not coming on ID 1002. The reason i think is that for ID 1001 the type column has an empty value or space but for ID 1002 type has a char value 'S'.In my table i have a lots of rows with empty values so what i can do to avoid this exception?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove "id" field from domain class.

Comment: why is that?ID is the primary key

Comment: because GORM do it by itself

Comment: Although declaring `id` in domain is redundant, removing it does not resolve this issue.

Comment: I've met many issues with grails-data-mapping 5.0.3 - 5.0.4, please upgrade it to 5.0.5 first. (Grails 3.1.6), may be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you indicate which attributes are `nullable` in `constraint` clause. In your case attribute superSub can be null:

```
superSub nullable: true, maxSize: 1
```

If you don't indicate nullable attribute in constraint clause, explicitly, Grails expect a value for those.

Comment: superSub is not nullable, all my columns are not nullable so i added nullable : false on each column but the issue still exists.

Comment: If that's the case why superSub doesn't have any value for record 1001?

Comment: superSub has value 'P'. Its the type column which has value blank space "  ".